# CC more than one person?

Tags: php

I have a form that emails information and am trying to add another person to CC. Here's what doesn't work for me (it only sends to the first person):

```
    $headers = "CC: " . "person1@test.com; person2@test.com; person3@test.com" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Can you add some more code for context? You may be overwriting `$headers` without realizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try commas instead of semi-colons.

```
$headers = "CC: " . "person1@test.com, person2@test.com, person3@test.com" .
```